# React 0.13.3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of null

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use react-router-component.

Getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of null

```
var Locations = Router.Locations;
var Location = Router.Location;

var NotFound = Router.NotFound;

var APP =
  React.createClass({
    render:function(){
      return (
        <Template>
          <Locations>
            <location path="/" handler={Frontpage} />
            <location path="/new-estate" handler={NewEstate} />
          </Locations>
        </Template>
        )
    }
  });
```

This line marked in console as one causing the error (marked by asterisks):

```
var RouteRenderingMixin = {

  renderRouteHandler: function(props) {
    var handler = this.state.handler;
    **props = assign({ref: this.state.match.route.ref}, props);**
    // If we were passed an element, we need to clone it before passing it along.
    if (React.isValidElement(handler)) {
      return cloneWithProps(handler, props);
    }
    return React.createElement(handler, props);
  }

};
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Well clearly `this.state.match.route` is undefined/null

Comment: Check out this issue: https://github.com/STRML/react-router-component/issues/110